# Rails Active Record Associations error- undefined method `temp' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I´m getting a undefined method `temp' for nil:NilClass when i try to access json.temp @location.recordings.last.temp...

I'm confused as to why this would be as i have the has_many set...

And it works in the console:

```
irb(main):003:0> Location.last.recordings.last.temp
  Location Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" ORDER BY "locations"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]                                 
  Recording Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "recordings".* FROM "recordings" WHERE "recordings"."location_id" = ? ORDER BY "recordings"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["location_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]                                               
=> 22
```

here is my code https://github.com/jrwrest/weather-app

if anyone has any input that would be great git code here

Following this lesson https://gorails.com/episodes/our-first-api

app/models/location.rb

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :recordings
end
```

app/models/recording.rb

```
class Recording < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Comment: Check whether there are recordings have for that location or not

Comment: yes i have that in the db https://i.imgur.com/KCYdrNn.jpg

Comment: Your github link 404s, even better than fixing that though would be to edit your question to show the two models involved.

Comment: ah sorry fixed the link and added the to models involved

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong url. In your database the location id is 4

Are you using the `localhost:3000/api/v1/locations/4.json`?

Comment: yes using that URL here is a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/379Bk5d.jpg

Comment: Can you give us the `db/development.sqlite3` file?